# TypeError: Cannot add property Quantity, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, typeerror

I'm getting this error -
`Cannot add property Quantity, object is not extensible` in Files.jsx

itemsInCart **array of objects** is defined at the App.jsx and getting filled in other **jsx component**, I checked with console.

**App.jsx**

```
const ItemsCartWithLocalStorage = (userItems) => {
  const itemsInCart = useRef(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userItems)) || new Array());
 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('localStorage setItem');
    localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(itemsInCart));
  }, [itemsInCart]);

  return [itemsInCart];

};
function App() {

const itemsInCart = useRef(ItemsCartWithLocalStorage('itemsQuantityString'));
return (
      <Files itemsInCart={itemsInCart} />
    )
   }
```

**Files.jsx**

```
const Files= ({ itemsInCart }) => {

 const array = [...itemsInCart.current]; 
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 array[i]['Quantity'] = 1;  "TypeError: Cannot add property Quantity, object is not extensible"
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: What is the structure of array?

Comment: Are you sure that `array[i]` is an object

Comment: @SinanYaman  you meant properties ? `[{CategoryName:  ""
Price: 26
ProductDescription:  ""
ProductID: 2
ProductImage:  ""
ProductName:  ""
ProductOverview:  ""
Stock: 290},{...}]`

Comment: @Rahul when `itemsInCart` was a state it worked really well, but I didn't want re-render so I made it `useRef` to array.

Comment: You don't have a `Quantity` field in the object. And since it is type-safe, it tells you that you can't add extra fields to the object. Therefore, you can't add quantity. Try changing price in the same line, and it will work.

Comment: Why are you using `ref` to prevent re renders, use `useMemo` or split the component b/w dynamic and static component. 
Other solution: save data into `localStorage/sessionStorage`

Comment: You must have set [`Object.preventExtensions()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) or any library you using did the same for you.

Comment: @Rahul I tried to call it `const numberOfItems = useMemo(() => {` but where shall I call it when `itemsInCart ` changed ?

Comment: @ExtraSun first learn `useMemo` and what it does. You need to wrap the component not normal data. When you'll wrap your component with `useMemo` then you can decide that when you want to rerender the component.

Comment: @Rahul you probably mixed with `memo` hook that wrapping the component

Comment: @ExtraSun i used to use `useMemo` to solve such kind of question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useRef.currrent - how to fix "Cannot read property 'current' of undefined, and more issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711409/useref-currrent-how-to-fix-cannot-read-property-current-of-undefined-and-m)

Comment: @Rahul I tried again with useMemo but its doesnt go checked - `const numberofItems = useMemo(() => {    console.log('numberofItems useMemo');
  }, [itemsInCart?.current]);`  no console nothing - `return ( <div className='cart-icon' value={numberofItems}>`

Comment: Why are you getting `itemsInCart.current` in `array` and updating , shouldn't you use `itemsInCart.current[0].current` as you are using `useRef` nested twice?

Comment: @ShivamSharma why `current[0].current` twice ? I didn't understand the *nested twice* part.

Comment: I have created [a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-frost-81yso?file=/src/App.js) similar to your code, check the console.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Sorry for my ignorance but I didn't see anywhere by googling and React docs  the `current[0].current` explanation. Where can I find an explanation about it ? Thank for the effort  still getting `TypeError: itemsInCart.current[0].current is not iterable
`

Comment: @ExtraSun `itemsInCart.current[0].current` is an `object` so you can not iterate over it.

Comment: @ExtraSun try `console.log(typeof itemsInCart.current[0].current)` you'll get the result

Comment: It doesn't require explanation, as in my example, In `Wrap`, `data.current = Array of 2 objects`, returned `[data] = Array with 1 element which is an Object having "current" set to Array of 2 objects`, Inside App, `useRef` is calling `Wrap` so `data.current` becomes `[data] = Array with 1 element which is an Object having "current" set to Array of 2 objects`, Now inside `Ele`, to access the main data, you will first get `dat.current` which is Array of 1 obj, then `data.current[0]` means that obj, then `data.current[0].current` means the exact data (Array of 2 objects).

Comment: If it's not iterable then you just need to log it and see what does it actually contains, it'll not be an Object or Array, so you can't add a key `"Quantity"` to it. It must be an immutable Object, I have updated my answer for the same.

Comment: @ShivamSharma I still can't understad how in your codesandbox the `[...data.current[0].current]` gives the whole array with two object, and in my code `const array = [...itemsInCart.current[0].current] gives an error.

Comment: @ExtraSun, Just `console.log` the value of `data.current` and you will get the answer, You might be storing a string in localstorage that is two times JSON stringified.

Comment: See if [this relates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798885/object-is-not-extensible-error-when-creating-new-attribute-for-array-of-objects) with your problem.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Did you mean here  - `localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(itemsInCart))` ? Without the `stringify` there is an error. Can we continue in a chat ?

Comment: @ShivamSharma `localStorage` takes only strings not objects thats why is has to be with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235793/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-extrasun).

Answer (score 0):

You must have set [`Object.preventExtensions()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) or any library you use is doing the same for you. After this call, you can't add new properties to the object passed as an argument in the call, and in your case, you might be adding the `"Quantity"` field and it was not in the origin object.

> The `Object.preventExtensions()` method prevents new properties from ever being added to an object (i.e. prevents future extensions to the object). [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)

> The JavaScript exception "can't define property "x": "obj" is not extensible" occurs when `Object.preventExtensions()` marked an object as no longer extensible, so that it will never have properties beyond the ones it had at the time it was marked as non-extensible. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible)

> In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), attempting to add new properties to a non-extensible object throws a TypeError. In sloppy mode, the addition of the "x" property is silently ignored. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible#adding_new_properties_to_a_non-extensible_objects)

Below is the code for replicating the same.

```js
'use strict';

const itemsInCart = {current:[{a:"a"},{a:"b"}]};
Object.preventExtensions(itemsInCart.current[1]);
const array = [...itemsInCart.current];
array[1]["q"] = 1
console.log(itemsInCart.current)
```

---

Or you might be trying to update an immutable object like `String` by adding the key `Quantity`. It's not possible in `strict` mode and we get `TypeError` while in Sloppy mode it's just ignored.

```js
'use strict';

const str = "abc";

str["Quantity"] = 1;
```

Comment: Not correct, when `itemsInCart`  was a `state` it worked and "Quantity" was added to the array object.

Comment: I am not sure about React may be the hooks like `useRef` are the culprit. Or as [prop are read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) so they might be having this `preventExtensions` set behind the scenes.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot add property q, object is not extensible` the same error with your code.

Comment: Yes, I was showing you that when this error occurs as you asked in the question "Why am I seeing this error?"

Comment: how to access nonextensible obj[k] dynamically via var k ?